# How to create a variable that identifies duplicate variables in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following columns A and B and would like to add an additional column C to identify duplicate values in column A as 'DUP'.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Use *window function* with `case` expression:

```
select *,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by colA) > 1
             then 'Duplicate' else 'Single' end) as Dup   
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create the new column `c`:

```
alter table my_table add c varchar(10);
```

Then, you update its value for the repeated rows only:

```
update my_table set c = 'DUP'
  where a in (
    select a from my_table group by a having count(*) > 1
    );
```